# как написать скрипт на js который будет убирать класс у одного объекта если он есть у другого

Tags: javascript

```html
<label id="zone1"> Доменное имя в зоне .ru<input type="checkbox" /><i></i></label>
<label id="zone2">Доменное имя в зоне .com<input type="checkbox" /><i></i></label>
```

Дело в таком, если нажимаешь на чекбокс с id zone1 то появляется класс active, и если после этого нажать на второй чекбокс то добавляется класс ко второму но удаляется с 1 чекбокса

Comment: Вам на чистом `js` или можно на `jquery`?

Comment: @Klimenkomud Может, ему еще и сопли вытереть?

Comment: без разницы, как вам угодно

Comment: @EmilRotatew читайте, изуйчайте: [добавить класс](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) [убрать класс](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: @Igor Все когда-то начинали и не знали что и как делать :) Другой вопрос что лично мне никогда не лень было покопаться в вопросе, и если нужно - подучить нужную технологию. А суть то достаточно проста: убрать класс у одного элемента добавить другому при событии. Гугл отвечает на этот вопрос отлично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на jQuery:

```
if( $("#zone1" ).hasClass("active") ) // если есть класс active у #zone1
{
    $("#zone2" ).removeClass("active"); // удаляем класс active у #zone2
}
```